# POST not working using express + bootstrap modal

Tags: node.js, express, post, bootstrap-modal

at the client side, the modal is defined as:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message to undefined</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="tag-name">Tag:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="tag-name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="url-name">URL:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="url-name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the server side, the app.js is defined as:

```
var express = require('express');
...
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
...
var app = express();
...
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

in the ./routes/index.js, I have this callback handler

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


/* POST handler. */
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
  console.log('post received')
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm expecting this result: when **Save** button is clicked, a **POST** request will be sent to the server side. and then "post received" will be printed in the console log. But in my implementation, nothing happened. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) you are missing attribute `action` and `method` in your `form` tag. So when you press `Send` browser don't know where to send data.

Could you try to add that two attributes like in example below?

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message to undefined</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="localhost:3000" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="tag-name">Tag:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="tag-name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="url-name">URL:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="url-name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a synchronous form submit, you will need  to tell what method you want (post or get) and where to send it. In your case, it may be something like

```
<form method="post" action="/">...</form>
```

Regards